# How to filter only a element from a sequence (IEnumerable) in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core

For example: `{ 1,2,3,4,5,3,6}.Filter(i => i.Equals(3))` will become `{1,2,4,5,3,6}`

My current way:

```
array
.TakeWhile(i => !i.Equals(min))
.Concat(array.SkipWhile(i => !i.Equals(min)).Skip(1))
```

I hope there is some way that will more elegant(shorter) than this

Comment: You have a Where function...

Comment: Where will filter multiple elements, what i want is just one element.

`{1,2,3,4,5,3,6}.Where(i =>! i.Equals(3))` => `{1,2,4,5,6}`.

What i want: 

`{1,2,3,4,5,3,6}.Filter(i => i.Equals(3))` => `{1,2,4,5,3,6}`.

Comment: Does it more elegant for you `int count = 0; { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6 }.Where(i => !i.Equals(3) || count++ > 0);`?

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria your approach is not work right

Comment: Fix it, check again please.

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria still not right way

Comment: will  `{ 1,2,3,4,5,3,6,3}` become to `{ 1,2,4,5,3,6}`?

Comment: @Snoob I think you have got it right, it is a very clever solution based on that fact that optimization will cause the second condition after `||` to evaluate only if the first `!i.Equals(min)` is `false`.

Comment: @Snoob - can you please explain better what you want?

Comment: oh, sorry, my mistake. George's solution is correct

Comment: It's not correct solution for this `{ 1,2,3,4,5,3,6,3}`. If you want has only one duplicated item from all duplications just fix `count++ > 0` to `count++ == 1` in my previous comment.

Comment: nope, your previous solution is correct. I want remove one element, not one duplicated item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where filter works like this but this what I use if I want to remove one item only from IEnumerable.

```
public static class LinqExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<TSource> RemoveOne<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
        {
            var found = false;
            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                if (!found && predicate(item))
                {
                    found = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return item;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, for more clear reading I think will be better if I will post it as answer not a comment.

```
var array = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6 };
int count = 0; 
array = array.Where(i => !i.Equals(3) || count++ > 0).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add Extension and more general method for @George Alexandria great answer:

```
public static class LinqExtentions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> RemoveNumberByCondition<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection,
       Func<T, bool> predicate, 
       int numberToRemove = 1)
    {
        var count = 0;
        return collection.Where(x => predicate(x) || ++count > numberToRemove).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var min = 3;
var arr = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 6 };
var res = arr.RemoveNumberByCondition(x => !x.Equals(min));
```

Comment: the best of both worlds ^^.

Comment: btw, your method is reversed, it should be something like this: `arr.WithoutOne(x => x.Equals(min));`

Comment: @Snoob fair enought.

Comment: @teovankot Looking at your follow up question, I guess now you understand why using LINQ operator with side effects is not a great idea at all. Iterator method similar to accepted answer is the right way, your initial answer worked *only* because of the `ToList` call which you removed.

Comment: @IvanStoev it's actually working without `ToList`. We only have different result in watch (debugger). Like you said - side effects of double execution.

Comment: No, it doesn't work in general. Try `var r1 = res.ToList(); var r2 = res.ToList();` and you'll see that the `r2` is wrong. If you use *iterator* method implementation (with `foreach` and `yield`) instead of LINQ, the result will be correct regardless of how many times you iterate it.

Comment: Can you explain more why `r2` is wrong, I am new to LINQ. For example, when i call `RemoveNumberByCondition` twice, it return the original seq (in case `ToList` is removed) : `arr.RemoveNumberByCondition(x => x.Equals(min)).RemoveNumberByCondition(x => x.Equals(min))`

Comment: @Snoob take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653370/linq-where-local-counter-closure-different-results-in-vs-watch) of mine. The answer is full enought to understand what's actually happends inside.

Comment: I think I can't sleep tonight :(

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> SkipFirstWhere<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
        if (predicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));
        return SkipFirstWhereIterator(source, predicate);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TSource> SkipFirstWhereIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
    {
        using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (!e.MoveNext()) yield break;
                if (predicate(e.Current)) break;
                yield return e.Current;
            }
            while (e.MoveNext())
                yield return e.Current;
        }
    }
}
```